# Application 'iGtalk' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, xcode4.2

I am running my application for 20-30 minutes i have checked the memory leaks there is no memory leaks in it. i am using MapView in my application which send it's location to server , after 20 minutes it work perfectly all rite but after 20 to 25 minutes it get crashed giving this logs

```
Sep 10 17:05:06 unknown UserEventAgent[19] <Notice>: jetsam: kernel termination snapshot being created
Sep 10 17:05:06 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilemail[0x585e]) Exited: Killed: 9
Sep 10 17:05:06 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.ephlux.VeloCity[0xfbfb]) Exited: Killed: 9
Sep 10 17:05:06 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.iappventures.gtalk[0x75e0]) Exited: Killed: 9
Sep 10 17:05:06 unknown SpringBoard[27] <Warning>: Application 'VeloCity' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
Sep 10 17:05:07 unknown com.apple.locationd[68] <Notice>: NOTICE,Location icon should now not be visible
Sep 10 17:05:07 unknown SpringBoard[27] <Warning>: Application 'Mail' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
> 
Sep 10 17:05:07 unknown SpringBoard[27] <Warning>: Application 'iGtalk' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
Sep 10 17:05:08 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: Sandbox: ignoring builtin profile for platform app: /private/var/stash/Applications/MobileMail.app/MobileMail
Sep 10 17:05:08 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[608] Builtin profile: container (sandbox)
Sep 10 17:05:08 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[608] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/124A80FF-4E09-4E60-8D3C-CE8C194F4801 [69] (sandbox)
> 
Sep 10 17:05:09 unknown ReportCrash[605] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Installing: (null) [ReportCrash] (675.00)
Sep 10 17:05:09 unknown iLocation[608] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Installing: com.iappventures.gtalk [iLocation] (675.00)
Sep 10 17:05:09 unknown MobileMail[606] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Installing: com.apple.mobilemail [MobileMail] (675.00)
Sep 10 17:05:09 unknown iLocation[608] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Activator.dylib
Sep 10 17:05:09 unknown MobileMail[606] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Activator.dylib
Sep 10 17:05:09 unknown ReportCrash[605] <Error>: Saved crashreport to /Library/Logs/CrashReporter/LowMemory-2012-09-10-170509.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 0 egid: 0
> 
Sep 10 17:05:11 unknown iLocation[608] <Warning>: Sound ID has been created
�> �> 
Sep 10 17:05:13 unknown com.apple.locationd[68] <Notice>: NOTICE,Location icon should now be visible
Sep 10 17:05:13 unknown iLocation[608] <Warning>: labelRect ={{10, 0}, {70, 41}}
Sep 10 17:05:13 unknown iLocation[608] <Warning>: self.textField.frame ={{100, -1}, {210, 43}}
Sep 10 17:05:13 unknown iLocation[608] <Warning>: labelRect ={{10, 0}, {70, 40}}
Sep 10 17:05:13 unknown iLocation[608] <Warning>: self.textField.frame ={{100, -1.5}, {210, 43}}
Sep 10 17:05:13 unknown iLocation[608] <Warning>: labelRect ={{10, 0}, {70, 39}}
Sep 10 17:05:13 unknown iLocation[608] <Warning>: self.textField.frame ={{100, -1}, {210, 43}}
Sep 10 17:05:13 unknown iLocation[608] <Warning>: labelRect ={{10, 0}, {70, 39}}
Sep 10 17:05:13 unknown iLocation[608] <Warning>: self.textField.frame ={{100, -1.5}, {210, 43}}
Sep 10 17:05:13 unknown spd[609] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Installing: (null) [spd] (675.00)
Sep 10 17:05:13 unknown wifid[49] <Error>: WiFi:[368971513.595893]: Disable WoW requested by "spd"
> 
Sep 10 17:05:15 unknown com.apple.locationd[68] <Notice>: NOTICE,Location icon should now not be visible
�> �> 
Sep 10 17:10:07 unknown SpringBoard[27] <Notice>: Posting 'com.apple.iokit.hid.displayStatus' notifyState=0
Sep 10 17:10:07 unknown SpringBoard[27] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: detection mode: 0->255
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more likely to happen when the memory usage of your application increases gradually. When a foreground application requires more memory, the OS kills the background applications one by one to make available as much of memory as possible to the foreground app. But when the memory usage of foreground app goes above the available amount of memory, the OS kills the foreground app also and generates crash report.